# Can't add url scheme in Callback URLs twitter develop app

Tags: ios, react-native, twitter, callback

I am working with twitter SDK to integrate with in ios app.When i follow all the step and create the customer key and put it in my app. But I can't add url scheme in Callback URLs twitter develop app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVxrM.png)

Comment: You need to add a valid URL in it.

Comment: I add scheme, not url, eg: scheme://